# For each loop need guidance

Tags: excel, if-statement, for-loop, vba

The idea is I want to evaluate each Ws in Workbook for a given criteria in vba. If the criteria is met I want it to do something. If it's not met I want to go to the next ws. I know this is simple stuff. Any help would be really appreciate

Here's what I have so far.

```
Sub dataconsol()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value = 1 Then
            Range("A1").Value = 2
        ElseIf Range("b9").Value <> 1 Then

        End If
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine. Switch ActiveSheet to With Ws as in your case ActiveSheet was always 'Sheet1'.

```
Sub dataconsol()

Dim Ws As Worksheet

For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If .Range("B9").Value = 1 Then
            .Range("A1").Value = 2
        ElseIf .Range("b9").Value <> 1 Then
        End If
    End With
Next Ws

End Sub
```

Or if you want to use ActiveSheet:

```
Sub dataconsol2()

Dim Ws As Worksheet

For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Ws.Activate
    If Range("B9").Value = 1 Then
        Range("A1").Value = 2
    ElseIf Range("b9").Value <> 1 Then
    End If
Next Ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. Can you explain what "With Ws" means and why it was necessary? Rudimentary  question, but I'm still putting together the basics (no put intended).

Comment: Explaination on With...End With statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx, short story long, it replaces using `Ws.Range` each time. You were using ActiveSheet without activating each sheet (so it was referencing to Sheet1 all the time).

Comment: I also put another version with Sheet.Activate if you need using ActiveSheet (`Ws.Activate` in this case)

Comment: Rafal, can you explain the difference between .range and range? Interestingly enough, the .range method was complicated for me to get working, whereas the second method succeeded almost immediately. Just curious why that would be.

Comment: It's kidnda same thing. Lone `Range` refers to sheet which is active at the moment. Look at second code I put in my answer, I'm activating each sheet I'm looping into and I can refer to it by `Range`.  `.Range` on the other hand refers to sheet I'm looping into because with `With...End With` it serves as `Ws.Range` which is pointing directly to worksheet I'm interested in.  Also you can use `Sheet("SheetName")` or `Sheet(x)` where x is sheet index (ie. 1).  I hope it clarifies a lil bit.